# Cannot install Windows 7 on new PC (BSOD during installation)

Tags: windows-7, bsod, hardware-failure, installation

Yesterday I received new hardware and tried to assemble all of it. But when I was installing Windows 7 x64 I got a BSOD twice, and the following error message:

> Your PC has rebooted unexpectly, installation will continue after reboot.

I have checked everything and tried to install one more time. It was almost successful, Windows had installed, but I cannot format my disk, open `cmd` or Control Panel, boot from DVD etc.

It's the first time I have assembled a PC, and I don't know where the problem is, in my hardware or in Windows.

My components:

- MSI z77a-g43
- Intel Core i5-3570K
- Seagate Barracuda (plugged into SATA 6 Gb/s slot, I also have a SATA 3 Gb/s slot)
- Corsair XMS3 (4x 4 GB)
- HIS IceQ

Also in the BIOS, I have changed RAM frequency to DDR3 1600 and voltage to 1.65 V.

**UPDATE**: I have removed the video card, sound card, and left only 4 GB of RAM, and restored BIOS defaults. I can now install Windows. However, my memory is specced at 1600 MHz and 1.65 V, but if I set these values in BIOS I have BSODs very often. AUTO setings show 1.5 V and 1333 MHz. Is this memory compatible with my MSI z77a-g43 or the Intel Core i5-3570K?

Comment: Your question is very broad and you may need to be prepared to try a few things; my advice would be to remove everything you can (so other than Keyboard/Mouse, no other things are plugged in), try the 3Gb slot and only use 1 GB ram. Then, try to reformat it and see if you get the same errors - if so, I would contact MSI and ask for a replacement.

Comment: Or, you may need to flash the bios first and then try the installation with your current set up (read your manual for M-Flash). I would recomment not messing about with BIOS settings (like RAM frequency etc) unless you have to or until after the OS installs. It does seem you've been very unlucky; did you format and partition the hard drive first?

Comment: During Windows installation in appropriate dialog I have divided HDD into 2 parts and choose one to install Windows. As for bios settings: on my RAM I have following - 1.65v 1600Mhz, in BIOS I have 1.5v and 1333, it doesnt change automatically.

Comment: Have you enabled overclocking in BIOS or via switch? I had a similar problem and had to disable overclocking until after Windows 7 was installed and operating.

Comment: @CharlieRB No, I have not enable overlocking, but I will check.

Comment: Try Install with only 1 stick of memory installed.

Comment: If I google XMS3 4x4, the first hit I get is a newegg page for 1333 memory. Have you confirmed the memory you have in your hand is what you think it should be? Model number would look something like this (CMX16GX3M4A1333C9). Also, there are other settings in addition to voltage and bus speed which need to be considered when setting manually (CAS latency  etc)

Comment: @horatio I have this Ram http://www.corsair.com/memory-by-product-family/xms-classic/cmx4gx3m2a1600c9.html

Comment: @andronz - It sounds like your trying to overclock your memory thus causing your computer to crash.  Use the auto setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tech specs on the page you linked to clearly show that the SPD settings are: "1333, 1.5v, 9-9-9-24" which matches what your BIOS reports. Frankly, I think the manufacturer is playing a little loose with the facts here.

Leave your memory setting in the BIOS on AUTO, and proceed with your install. After you have the computer running properly, use a program such as [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to get a better look at what the memory reports in SPD.

You can then experiment with adjusting the timings if you want. I doubt it will really be worth the trouble: the synthetic benchmarks will probably say you have faster memory, but real world usage will probably show an underwhelming or unnoticable difference.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I was confused with this: Tested Voltage 1.65, Tested Speed 1600Mhz, and on my RAM I have the same title. Now I'm activated XMP and set 1600 and 1.54, now works fine.

Comment: Do I need to disable XMP and set auto settings?

Comment: I don't really know what XMP refers to in this context, unless I am just not thinking straight. The problem here is that you are actually overclocking the memory. The computer may run fine until you try and play a game and sometimes only certain games will cause the problem. So my advice is that *IF* you find instant rebooting or BSODs happening, remember to first go and set the memory back to auto (SPD) and see if the problem resolves.